# Calculating $E(Z\mid Y)$ and $E(Y\mid Z)$ where $Z$ is exponential and $Y=1_{1\le Z\le 2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Given

$$Z \sim \text{Exp}(1)\qquad,\qquad Y = \begin{cases} 1, & \mbox{if } 1\leq Z\leq2 \\ 0, & \mbox{else} \end{cases}$$

I want to calculate $E(Z\mid Y)$ and $E(Y\mid Z)$.

Since $Y$ is a discrete random variable, I figured that

$$E(Z\mid Y)=E(Z\mid Y=1)1_{\{Y=1\}}+E(Z\mid Y=0)1_{\{Y=0\}}$$

which is equal to $$E(Z\mid Y=1)1_{\{1\leq Z \leq 2\}}+E(Z\mid Y=0)(1-1_{\{1\leq Z \leq 2\}})$$

But I am not sure how to continue.

Also, given $E(Z\mid Y)$ could I apply something like Bayes rule but for conditional expectation to get $E(Y\mid Z)$?

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{E}[Y\vert Z]=Y$ simply because $Y$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(Z)$?

Comment: Why is $Y$ measurable with respect to $\sigma(Z)$?

Comment: Since $Y$ is an indicator of the event $\{  1 \leq Z\leq 2 \}$, it is sufficient to check whether this event is in $\sigma(Z)$. But this is clearly true, since $Z$ is a random variable.

Comment: Maybe useful—note that $\mathbb{E}(Z | Y=1)=\mathbb{E}(Z| 1 \leq Z\leq 2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{G}] $ is defined as the unique (almost surely) random variable $W$ measurable with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ such that:

$\mathbb{E}  \Big[ \mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{G}]\cdot1_A \Big]= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot 1_A]$ for all $A\in \mathcal{G}$.

As a consequence if $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{G}]=X$. Hence $\mathbb{E}[Y\vert Z]=Y$ , since $Y$ is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable.

On the other hand $\sigma{(Y)}= \Big\{ \emptyset, \Omega, \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \}, \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \}^c \Big\}$, and therefore:

$\mathbb{E}[Z\vert Y]=a\cdot 1_{ \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \} }+ b\cdot 1_{ \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \}^c }$ as you wrote. Checking the definition, you will see that:

$a=\mathbb{E}[Z\cdot 1_{ \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \} }]=\mathbb{E}[Z| 1 \leq Z\leq 2]$ and $b=\mathbb{E}[Z\cdot 1_{ \{ 1\leq Z\leq 2 \}^c }]=\mathbb{E}[z]-a$.

Then by the definition of $Exp(1)$, you can tell that:

$a=\int_1^2 xf_Z(x)dx=\int_1^2 xe^{-x}dx$